# How can I make a script for run another script

Tags: linux, shell, move

I would like to run obj2opengl.pl with all files in

> /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object

which are name A001.obj A002.obj ...
After run the script, I will get A001.h A002.h ... and I would like to move these files to

> /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Header

How can I adapt this code below
*the problems are at A${i}.obj and A${i}.h

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object
start=1
n=$(find . -name "*.obj" | wc -l)
end=$(($n));
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
./obj2opengl.pl "A${i}.obj"
mv "A${i}.h" /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Header
done
```

If I adapt my code by using if statement , How can I fix this code for the right syntax For example:

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object
start=1
a=0
b=0
c=1
n=$(find . -name "*.obj" | wc -l)
end=$(($n));
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
   ./obj2opengl.pl "A${a}${b}${c}.obj"
   mv "A${i}.h" /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Header
   c++
if[$c > 9] then
   b++
   c=0
fi
if[$b>9] then
   a++
   b=0
   c=0
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object

find . -name "A*.obj" -exec obj2opengl.pl {} \;
find . -name "A*.h" -exec mv {} /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Header \;
```

Comment: it's error. find: obj2opengl.pl: No such file or directory. But I already put obj2opengl.pl in /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object

Comment: @kantawit, change it to `-exec ./obj2opengl.pl`

Comment: There are not .h file .It seem I should type the file name eg. dog.obj after find . -name "A*.obj" -exec ./obj2opengl.pl because It told that Usage:
     obj2opengl [options] file

     use -help or -man for further information

Answer (score 0):

```
if[$c > 9] then
   b++
```

I think here is the syntax error. `[` is a command in shell, it takes one or more args, and the last arg must be `[`, so you must use space to seperate the command and args, and also need space between `if` and `[`.

Another error, shell do not support c style `++`， you can use `b=$[b+1]`.

Here is the correct code:

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object
start=1
a=0
b=0
c=1
n=$(find . -name "*.obj" | wc -l)
end=$(($n));
for((i=$start;i<=$end;i++))
do
   ./obj2opengl.pl "A${a}${b}${c}.obj"
   mv "A${i}.h" /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Header
   c=$[c+1]
if [ $c > 9 ] then
   b=$[b+1]
   c=0
fi
if [ $b > 9 ] then
   a=$[a+1]
   b=0
   c=0
fi
done
```

Comment: It's error. It told me that line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Answer (score 0):

bash is not C, `for`, `if` and `[` are all commands and require whitespace to separate them from other words.

Use

```
cd /Users/KanZ/Desktop/Project/Test/Model/Object
for file in *.obj
do
    h=${file%.obj}.h
    ./obj2opengl.pl "$file"
    mv "$h" ../Header
done
```

See the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to explain the `${file%.obj}` part

If you want to count, don't keep track of leading zeroes manually, use `printf`:

```
max_width=${#end}
for ((i=$start; i<=$end; i++)); do
    printf -v n "%0*d" $max_width $i
    obj="A$n.obj"
    h="A$n.h"
    ./obj2opengl.pl "$obj" 
    mv "$h" ../Header
done
```